# Import WebCrypto Key on iOS9 Mobile Safari

Tags: mobile-safari, ios9, webcrypto-api

What does this error mean on Mobile Safari?

> Only ArrayBuffer and ArrayBufferView objects can be passed as
>   CryptoOperationData

The offending code is this:

```
return (window.crypto.subtle||window.crypto.webkitSubtle).importKey(
  "raw"
, key.buffer
, {  name: "HMAC"
  , hash: { name: "SHA-1" }
  }
, false
, ["sign", "verify"]
)
```

Note that `key` is `new Uint8Array([251, 23, 127, ... ])` and therefore `key.buffer` ought to be an instance of `ArrayBuffer`.

What does iOS want from me!?!?

**UPDATE**

False alarm. Mobile Safari is missing `TypedArray.prototype.slice`, which was being polyfilled  elsewhere with `Array.prototype.slice`, which caused the object to not be a buffer.